# Subdomain redict to www

Tags: apache, redirect, subdomain

I have the domain `example.com` and the `test.example.com` running on apache server. For some reason when I try to visit *test.example* it is redirected to *www.test.example* and by consequence a `Server not found` error is displayed in the browser. Both .htaccess (root and subdomain folder) files are empty.

**Additional facts**

I have another subdomain `xyz.example.com` pointed to public_html/xyz directory with some content inside (index.html with "hello world message") and it works fine if I use xyz.example.com instead of www.xyz.example.com. So, can you help me to point to the right direction in order. I have a vps and I am able to change any file if is required.

Below you can find my virtual host configuration.

```
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    ServerAlias www.test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/test
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/test.example.com combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/test.example.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I  .\n%{%s}t %O ."

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/public_html/test/cgi-bin/

    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/example/test.example.com/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in bind config zones you dont set subdomain test 
add this line in example.com zone >>

```
test.example.com         IN        A         (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is ip of your server

or you dont enable your virtual host config >>

```
a2ensite test.example.com
```

test.example.com is name of virtual host file.

Comment: I have checked the first option and it is correct. So, how can I enable (if it is not) teh virtual host?